# Image not scrolling with page react native

Tags: android, react-native

New in `react-native`, I am trying to create a registration page with an image at the top of the page.

[image]

I have achieved that but the issue the image does not scroll with the page. As the form is long and while trying to fill the form when the focus is on the `textbox` and the `keyboard` control comes up the form scroll while the `image` remain static.

Style:

```
imageContainer: {
    flex: .7,
    width: null,
    height: null
  },
  logoContainer: {
    flex: .7,
    marginTop: deviceHeight / 8,
  },
  logo: {
    position: "relative",
    left: Platform.OS === "android" ? 25 : 50,
    top: Platform.OS === "android" ? 35 : 60,
    width: 365,
    height: 100
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 45,
    fontWeight: "300",
    color: "#FFF",
    fontFamily: "'Quicksand', sans-serif"
  },
  titleButton: {
    height: 45,
    lineHeight: 45,
    fontSize: 11,
    textTransform: "uppercase",
    letterSpacing: 2.5,
    fontWeight: 500,
    color: "#000 !important",
    backgroundColor: "#85C227",
    border: "none",
    borderRadius: 45,
    cursor: "pointer",
    outline: "none",
    paddingLeft:40,
    paddingRight:40,
    textAlign: "center  !important",
    alignSelf: "center" 
  }
  ,
  text: {
    color: "#FFF",
    bottom: 6,
    marginTop: 5,
    fontSize: 30,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },

  firstrow: {
    flex: .7,
  },

  secondrow: {
    flex: 2,
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flex` is messing up your views. For a start use `Dimensions` to partition your screen based on screen height. `const height = Dimensions.get('window').height`. Then wrap your view with a `ScrollView`

Comment: I tried bringing in ScrollView but it is causing error.

Comment: What error? Try removing all flex in your styles and work your way up.

Comment: The ScrollView works. Forgot to include ScrollView  in my import.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an [Image](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image) instead of an [ImageBackground](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imagebackground) for your use case.

The [position](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#position) of the ImageBackground is probably set to `absolute`.
This sets the image position relative to the parent (which in this case is the entire screen)

You can remove this line because the default value for `position` is `relative`.

Comment: I did all that and I am still getting the same result.